# Action isn't working perfect on wordpress archive pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I've written a plugin that zooms in and out the text. It works fine in single post or page but doesn't work in archive and other pages that are generated with query. the "div" I've generated with plugin for zoom control repeats on those pages. so the jquery isn't working because I've used click event on a specific div id. here is my php code for plugin

http://pastebin.com/bA2DmKaf

Comment: you answered your own question - dont use ID selectors, use class instead

Comment: but the div is generating several times while adding the action on "the_content". how can i do only once on home page??